# How to make relay for WSDL server?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, sms

I have a web service access from my server IP, But I want to make an script and place on my server to let enduser connected to the script as relay for WSDL (requests and responses - SMS Services).

It's like a branch from the base. however I need to count requestes on my scripts too.

- Unfortunately I don't have access to WSDL server code.
- Also the enduser have to use the original WSDL (SOAP - php) client and I can't change enduser codes too.

So I have to ask enduser to connect to my server just like the original WSDL server then relay any request to WSDL server and same for resposes.

I can write a big class and Peer to Peer with many lines of codes. but I think there are better way for do this.

Any better Idea or solution?

Answer (score 1):

To provide service orchestration, as SOAP web services are service interface based, it's better to implement the source WSDL on your side. Also, you have an option to set up a **pass-through** reverse proxy and the key point is **rewriting** SOAP requests and response address URL to your proxy server address. There are some solutions:

1. Use Nginx as a reverse proxy here is a related article by [Jeff Geerling](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/reverse-proxying-soap-api-accessed-phps-soapclient).
2. With WSO2 ESB you can set up [pass-through SOAP proxy](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Pass+Through+Proxy+Template) and inject your logic code, as far as I know, it supports PHP (I already did it with Java).
3. Write an HTTP reverse proxy program with PHP and don't forget to rewrite SOAP, WSDL requests and response address URLs with proxy server address. Here is an [example](http://techzinger.blogspot.com/2007/07/writing-reverse-proxy-in-php5.html).

You have another option to orchestrate the SMS service and counter service as a Restful service and make it transparent for the client.

Comment: Your first solution will missed a stage to counting end user requests and the last one is not optimized solution. The second one is better I have to check it.

Comment: All solutions don't force the client to change their code. For the third solution, there is no worry about optimization and it depends to your implementation.

Comment: On the other hand, you have to consider your clients have access to your source SMS service and potentially they can invoke it directly. In this way, your counter doesn't work perfectly.

Comment: Here as  said, there is not any access to both side. I'm working on something to my early solution now. a little SOAP server that work like mirror to the base server.
It's make call based on reqeusts but not for invoking the actual call and this is the stage for me.
I try to make a dynamic function adder for my SOAP server, that gained on the fly depended on the end user request, so I don't need to write thosend lines of code and WSDL. My result will work with any diffrent WSDL service  too !